# history parameter has been removed from router in version 6.2.1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, router

I'm trying to use createMemoryHistory on the router and I'm getting the typescript error :{

the code is this and the message is in the image..

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'

const history = createMemoryHistory()

const makeSut = () => {
  const sut = render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Login />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code as plain text instead of screenshot and make sure your issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer needed to create the `history` object yourself. Use the `BrowserRouter` component instead or the `Router` component

Answer (score 0):

the test I'm doing is on the object's history,

I found this solution

```
<Router navigator={history} location={history.location}>
...
</Router>
```